# Getting values for distinct rows based on multiple columns

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have an example table below:

| ID | work_date | country | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 15/01/2022 | UK | 100 |
| 1 | 15/01/2022 | US | 100 |
| 1 | 15/04/2022 | US | 150 |
| 3 | 15/02/2022 | France | 500 |
| 3 | 15/02/2022 | Germany | 500 |

How can I create a measure to add to a chart visual such that the value column is only summed based on distinct values in the `ID` and `work_date` column (country does not need to be unique). E.g. in a chart visual, ID 1 would have 100 in January 2022 and 150 in April 2022. ID 3 would have value 500 in February 2022.

Currently, it would add up all the values (ID 1 would have 200 in January 2022).

I'm currently using:

```
SUMX(SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Table[ID], Table[work_date], "new_value", MAX(Table[value])), [new_value])
```

The summed figure is correct when presented in a card visual, but I get the error

> SummarizeColumns() and AddMissingItems() may not be used in this
> context when applied to a chart visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Measure = 
SUMX(SUMMARIZE('Table','Table'[ID],'Table'[work_date], "x", MAX('Table'[value])), [x])
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Is it because SUMMARIZECOLUMNS is incompatible with chart visuals?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure as I have never seen that error before. Have a read at SQLBI.com for best practices.